# Having trouble getting past Server error 500 with C++ CGI

Tags: c++, apache, cgi

I'm trying to get this simple C++ to give the browser output to display. After I submit a form, it's supposed to call this guy that's in my cgi-bin as a .cgi file.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
   cout << "Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n";
   cout << "<html>\n";
   cout << "<head>\n";
   cout << "<title>Hello World - First CGI Program</title>\n";
   cout << "</head>\n";
   cout << "<body>\n";
   cout << "<h2>Hello World! This is my first CGI program</h2>\n";
   cout << "</body>\n";
   cout << "</html>\n";

   return 0;
}
```

I set both my cgi-bin directory as well as my .cgi C++ program to permissions 755, but it still gives me a server error 500. I am pretty sure the path to my cgi-bin is correct too. Any ideas?

Comment: This will have much more to do with your web server configuration than with any code you have written. Check your web server error log.

Comment: How do i access the server log?

Comment: That depends on how your web server is set up. If you don't know, ask the person who set up your web server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you compile the file and set this as your .cgi? Might be the problem if you are trying to just access the script without compiling first, (easy to make the mistake if you are used to working in PHP / other scripting languages)

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](//stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment). I'm flagging this post for deletion.